# How does recursion traversing through trees

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

```
java version "1.8.0_92"
```

I am studying trees and how to traverse them using recursion. But I am confused about it works.

```
  public void preOrder(BinaryTree root) {
        if(root != null) {
            System.out.println(root);
            preOrder(root.leftChild);  <-- this gets called and will start from the top of the function
            preOrder(root.rightChild); <-- how can this get called if the top one will always calls itself?
        }
    }
```

I think that the second preOrder will never get called as the call above will always call itself so the second one will never be executed.

Comment: The second preOrder will always be called, since `root != null`

Comment: BTW, I know this question has been asked at least twice before; I can't find the previous ones after 10 minutes of seraching.

Comment: @Paulo So when the first preOrder(root.left) == null. The second preOrder(root.right) will be called? When the second root.right == null. The first preOrder(root.left) will be called again. Until both are == to null. Is that correct?

Comment: @ant2009 the JVM executes instruction-by-instruction, since there is no exception. In your case, if the first instruction is executed `preOrder(root.leftChild)` and it does not throw any exception, I can ensure to you that the second instruction `preOrder(root.rightChild);` will be executed too.

Comment: You should use debug mode and execute your code step-by-step to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does *not* always call itself.  It keeps going until it bottoms out with a null leftChild.  Then execution returns without doing anything -- it backs up one level and recurs on the rightChild of the lowest-level parent node.  When that call also runs out of children, the execution returns from handling this lowest-level parent node, again backing up one call, and does the rightChild of *that* node ... until the entire tree has been traversed.

Answer (score 1):

Once `root.leftChild` becomes null (ie, when you get to a leaf of the tree), `preOrder` will be called like so: `preOrder(null)`. When this happens, the condition will evaluate to `false`, and recursion unwind and stop, at which point `preOrder(root.rightChild)` will be evaluated.

Here's a call trace (in Scala):

```
case class BinaryTree(nodeName: String, leftChild: Option[BinaryTree], rightChild: Option[BinaryTree]) {
    def preOrder(root: Option[BinaryTree], depth: Int = 0) {
        root match {
            case Some(root) => {
                println(" " * depth + root.nodeName)
                preOrder(root.leftChild, depth+4)
                preOrder(root.rightChild, depth+4)
            }
            case None => println(" " * depth + "leaf")
        }
    }
}


val tree = new BinaryTree(
    "root", 
    Some(new BinaryTree(
        "a",
         Some(new BinaryTree("aa", None, None)),
         Some(new BinaryTree("ab", None, None)))),
    Some(new BinaryTree(
        "b",
        Some(new BinaryTree("ba", None, None)),
        Some(new BinaryTree("bb", None, None)))))


tree.preOrder(Some(tree))

root
    a
        aa
            leaf
            leaf
        ab
            leaf
            leaf
    b
        ba
            leaf
            leaf
        bb
            leaf
            leaf
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of it has as opening up a whole bunch of doors until you find what you're looking for, then you have to go back and close/check the other ones.

```
public void preOrder(BinaryTree root) {
    if(root != null) {
        System.out.println(root);
        preOrder(root.leftChild);  <-- this gets called and will start from the top of the function
        preOrder(root.rightChild); <-- how can this get called if the top one will always calls itself?
    }
}
```

We can replace the preOrder calls with the matching code to look like:

```
public void preOrder(BinaryTree root) {
    if(root != null) { <-- note the if check
        System.out.println(root);

        if(root.leftChild!= null) { <-- note the if check
            System.out.println(root.leftChild.leftChild);
            preOrder(root.leftChild.leftChild);  <- this expands into another if block
            preOrder(root.leftChild.rightChild); <- this also expands
        }

       if(root.rightChild!= null) { <-- note the if check
            System.out.println(root.rightChild.leftChild);
            preOrder(root.rightChild.leftChild);  
            preOrder(root.rightChild.rightChild);
        }

    }
}
```

It keeps expanding outwards... until you hit the special "base" if conditional that stops the recursion. In this case it is when you've found a leaf node of the tree, i.e. node == null, it stops the expansion because the if conditional is no longer true and everything begins to collapse in on itself, or in other words it can continue executing normally down the block of code.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion may seem to be confused when you just start to learn. Firstly, you can think of a subproblem. For preOder, it always prints out the root node, and left node, then right node. All you need is to solve a subproblem. (a basic simple tree below)

```
     root
    /    \
  left  right
  /        \
...        ...
```

Now go back to look at the code:

```
 if(root != null) {
    System.out.println(root);
    preOrder(root.leftChild);  // the left node now becomes another root, and keep making the next left node root until the next left node is null.
    preOrder(root.rightChild); // this line of code won't be executed until the last preOrder function call its root == null(hit the condition.)
 }
```

Trust recursion; it will always do the rest of part for you if your condition is correct. I agree to run debug mode to have a better understanding. It is very useful to learn how to use "step in" when you try to understand how code works.